# Wordpress editable template fields

Tags: templates

I created several template files like this:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: My Template 1
*/

get_header('my-template-1');
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
  the_content();
endwhile;
get_footer('my-template-1');

?>
```

I can assign a template to each page of my site.

**Question:**

How can I make specific portions of these templates to be editable in admin?

For example, I wish to have a field (which is assigned to one template) with some specific text in it, and if I edit and save this field - the updated text should appear in all pages that use this specific template.

Answer (score 2):

Custom fields can accomplish what you're trying to do. http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields

You define the custom key and values in an edit page, and then you can re-use them in other edit pages. Once defined, you need to display the custom fields in your template(s). The documentation isn't super clear, but if your key was "currently_reading", your php in your template would look something like,

```
get_post_meta($post_id, 'currently_reading');
```

...which would spit out "Calvin and Hobbes" for that particular page.

There are also plugins that can dress up the wp-admin area and the syntax, rather than just a textarea or text field and the custom field key slug. I use Advanced Custom Fields in almost every site I make: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/ . There's a free and pro version.

Comment: You proposed to use custom fields for posts or pages, but I need custom fields for templates. After editing a custom field on a page, the update will appear only on that page. But, I need to edit a custom field on a template, where the update should appear on all pages that use this template.

Comment: I think I understand now. You want a consistent value among pages. The shortest way is probably to reference a specific page/post_id in get_post_meta(), where that post is where you enter the value that the different pages share. You can also set consistent values via theme option http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages , or a widge http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API#Displaying_Widgets_and_Widget_Areas .